# Simple power series convergence question

Tags: calculus, power-series

So for my particular power series, I find that my interval of convergence is 
$-3 < x < 3$, so $R = 3$.

I do a nth term test on the original equation with -3 and 3 and find that the series converges on these values. Does that mean the series is absolutely convergent at $-3 < x < 3$ and conditionally convergent at $x=\pm3$?

edit: sorry if I didn't format correctly

edit 2: So my problem in particular is finding the series' radius and interval of convergence for $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{(x)^n}{x^{3/2}(3^n)}$ and it seems that x will converge for -3 and 3. How do I test for conditional convergence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does that mean the series is absolutely convergent at $−3<x<3$

Yes.

> and conditionally convergent at $x=\pm3$?

Not necessarily. Think of $\sum{x^n\over n^2}$: it clearly converges absolutely at both ends. Think of... well, in fact it takes some ingenuity to find a series that would actually converge conditionally at both ends; looks like $\sum(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}\cdot{x^n\over n}$ would do.

What we can definitely rule out is conditional convergence at one end **simultaneously** with absolute convergence at another end; that's impossible for sure.